# Determine javascript/css domains based on where published

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I have creatd a solution in Visual Studio 2013 which comprises two web application projects `Core.Web` and `App.Web`. `Core.Web` uses the url `web.core.dev`. `App.Web` uses the url `web.app.dev`.

`Core.Web` contains several javascript and css files that can be shared between projects. `App.Web` references these javascript files. `App.Web` may have an html file like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>App1.Web</title>
    <!-- core javascript -->
    <script src="//web.core.dev/Javascript/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//web.core.dev/Javascript/Ticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <!-- local javascript -->
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- core css -->
    <link href="//web.core.dev/Style/Reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//web.core.dev/Style/Global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- local css -->
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine locally. But when I come to publish live these links will not work unless I change them manually (`web.core.dev` changed to `core.mywebsite.com`). I would like to be able to publish the project and not have to worry about changing the local hrefs to live hrefs.

Is there a standard strategy that allows the domains to be changed depending on where they are published? A strategy that works for both `.aspx` and `.html` files?

Comment: You could use AppSettings in web.config and transform the configuration files to your build profile..

Comment: @TryingToImprove This would work for aspx pages but could you suggest how this could work for plain html files? This must be a common problem not just for .NET applications, therefore there must be a standard solution?